# how to show the user an error after raise ActiveRecord::Rollback in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a user after I create a client, but if the user already exists I roll back the transaction, but how do I tell the user something happened with a notice?

So far I have

```
def create
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @affiliate = Affiliate.new(affiliate_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if  @affiliate.save
          if User.find_by_email(user_params[:email]).nil?
          @user = User.create!(user_parameter)        
          format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thanks for your submission'}
          format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @affiliate}
          else
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback

          end
        else
          format.html {render :signup, layout: "sign-ups"}
          format.json {render json: @affiliate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried using the render and redirect but none worked.

Comment: Why not just check the user before saving the affiliate, or make it a model validation?

Comment: I think, generally, raising during expected conditions and manual rollbacks are both code-smells in a Rails app,,,

Comment: Im new to programming and i got to this point by following peoples advices. Your imput makes the most sense and I feel dumb not to have thought about this before. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, but please don't feel dumb for learning. I expected someone to come by with a "real" answer by now... For completeness sake, I summarized the comments above into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, both raising exceptions while encountering expected conditions and manual rollbacks are considered code-smells in a Rails application.

A more idomatic approach might involve checking the existence of the user before saving the affiliate in the controller, or moving the logic into a model validation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question w/o re-engineering everything, you could simply check `performed?` since all other paths render.

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    ...
      format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thanks for your submission'}
      format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @affiliate}
    ...
    else
    ...
      format.html {render :signup, layout: "sign-ups"}
      format.json {render json: @affiliate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    ...
    end
  end

  unless performed?
    # render duplicate email notice, re-display form
  end
end
```

That said, below is a more typical approach. There are still some subtle issues but they would require diving into the specifics of your application.

```
# Add #email unique validation to User model, if not already implemented.
#   class User < ApplicationRecord
#     ...
#     before_validation :normalize_email # downcase, etc
#     validates :email, unique: true # should unique constraint on DB also
#     ...
#   end

def create
  success = nil

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @affiliate = Affiliate.new(affiliate_params)
    @affiliate.save

    # I'm guessing there is a relationship between the Affiliate and
    # the User which is not being captured here?

    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save

    # Validation errors will populate on both @affiliate and @user which can
    # be presented on re-display (including duplicate User#email).

    # Did both the @affiliate and @user validate and save?
    success = @affiliate.persisted? && @user.persisted?

    # If one or both failed validation then roll back
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless success
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if success
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thanks for your submission' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @affiliate }
    else
      # Either @affiliate or @user didn't validate. Either way, errors should
      # be presented on re-display of the form. Json response needs work.
      format.html { render :signup, layout: "sign-ups" }
      format.json { render json: @affiliate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why use a rollback, when you can just check the success of the operation? I'm sorry, but this is n't a good approach at all...

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't want the Affiliate to persist if the user is a duplicate, hence the rollback (as in his original code).

Comment: The original code uses `User.find_by_email(user_params[:email]).nil?` ... Not only have you suggested a poor approach, but you have changed the original code...